# Number of Discussions and number of Replies, do not show updated results, inside my community site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, community

I have a community site inside my SharePoint 2013 , but I have noted that the number of Discussions and number of Replies counters inside the community site home page, do not display the most recent results.

For example we use to have 3 discussions and 1 reply, and the user delete his discussion and his reply. So  currently we should have 2 discussions and zero replies. But the counters are still displaying 3 discussions and one reply.

So Can anyone advice how to force these counters to display the most up-to-date counting results ?
Thanks

Comment: We are facing the same exact problem, even the class icon tiles are showing the wrong count of topics/replies. Have you found a solution for this? :)

Comment: not really , i even applied the latest CU for SharePoint (Sept 2014), but it did not solve this issue. i remember that i find a solution, but this will cause any modification inside the discussion forum such as left side link , etc to be lost !!. so till now the counters are wrong :)

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer! I made a support ticket about this too.. maybe it helps Microsoft to notice the bug/problem! ;-)

Comment: Did you get any solution from Microsoft support about this ? I m facing a similar issue with my discussion communities.