# SP2013 Community Site category tiles: "Discussions" and "Replies" counts are frozen after migration

Tags: 2013, discussion-board, community-site, community

We recently moved a SharePoint 2013 Community site from a test environment to our company's live environment, where it has been getting regular use.  It now has about 30 members and 30 discussion divided into 5 categories.  The problem is that on the "Categories" page, the promoted links tiles do not show accurate numbers of discussions and replies in each category on mouseover.  They seem to have frozen at some point before the migration - some of the categories show 0 discussions and replies, even though they are not actually empty.

This question is similar to these questions:

- [POST 1](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114793/spo-2013-community-site-category-tiles-showing-incorrect-amount-of-topics-repl)
- [POST 2](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79563/number-of-discussions-and-number-of-replies-do-not-show-updated-results-inside)

However, those questions
 (a) address a slightly different situation (we want to display *more* conversations, not fewer), and
 (b) seem to have never been satisfactorily resolved.

We have tried ensuring that "`Allow items to be rated`" is set to "`Yes`" in Site Settings.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

EDIT: The list containing discussions shows the categories that each discussion has, and the list containing categories shows the incorrect counts for at least two categories.

Answer (score 0):

is active directory same for test and production environment? If the user count differs then both the data will be mismatch.

Also check if all the features on test and production are same.
Check for the list where user replies are saved.
In case, not solved, provide more details.

Comment: Active Directory is the same in both environments, and we aren't having any trouble with user counts.  When you say "features" what exactly are you talking about?  Features enabled on the server, or settings on the site?  I am updating the original question with screenshots.

Comment: Sorry, with explanation -- not enough reputation for more links.